# proof that halting problem is undecidable

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, undecidability, halting-problem

In the book Formal languages and automata by Peter Linz, 4th edition (Jones & Bartlett Learning), on pages 300-301,
there is a proof for the fact that the halting problem is undecidable.

The proof is as follows:

We show that there is no TM $H$ that solves the halting problem.

1. Assume there is a TM $H$ that solves the halting problem.
2. We require that:

- H's input is $w_M w$
- $H$ halt in either $q_Y$ or $q_N$ appropriately (illustrate):
  $$
  q_0 w_M w \vdash_H^* x_1 q_Y x_2,
  $$
  if $M$ halts on $w$, and
  $$
  q_0 w_M w \vdash_H^* y_1 q_N y_2,
  $$
  if $M$ does not halt on $w$.

3. Modify $H$, producing $H^{\prime}$, where $q_Y$ is not final (illustrate):
   $q_0 w_M w \vdash_{H^{\prime}}^* \infty$
   if $M$ halts on $w$, and
   $q_0 w_M w \vdash_{H^{\prime}}^* y_1 q_N y_2$
   if $M$ does not halt on $w$.
4. Modify $H^{\prime}$, producing $\widehat{H}$, which:
   (a) copies $w_M$ : Make $M$ 's input a description of itself
   (b) behaves like $H^{\prime}$ thereafter:
   $$
   q_0 w_M \vdash_{\widehat{H}}^* q_0 w_M w_M \vdash_{\widehat{H}}^* \infty,
   $$
   if $M$ halts on $w_M$, and
   $$
   q_0 w_M \vdash_{\widehat{H}}^* q_0 w_M w_M \vdash_{\widehat{H}}^* y_1 q_N y_2,
   $$
   if $M$ does not halt on $w_M$.
5. If $\widehat{H}$ 's input is a description of itself, then
   $$
   q_0 w_{\widehat{H}} \vdash_{\widehat{H}}^* \infty,
   $$
   if $\widehat{H}$ halts on $w_{\widehat{H}}$ (a contradiction), and
   $$
   q_0 w_{\widehat{H}} \vdash_{\widehat{H}}^* y_1 q_N y_2,
   $$
   if $\widehat{H}$ does not halts on $w_{\widehat{H}}$ (a contradiction).

**My question:**

During an exam I said that we are doing the reverse of the original machine, but I was told that we are not doing the reverse since we are not modifying anything on the side of the "no" answer. However: does that piece of the automaton also lead to a contradiction? Or is it just the yes branch that returns opposite answer? On the Internet I read that when we get a "no" answer we return a "yes" answer, and when we get a "yes" answer we start an infinite loop. However, this is not what is happening here, is it? Would someone like to clarify this?

Comment: In the proof you outline the machine supposedly returns No if the target machine doesn't halt. But that's a contradiction, because given itself as input, it halts (returning No) if it doesn't halt. (And it doesn't halt if it does halt).

Comment: @rici thank you. So if I understood correctly, we didn't have to change anything when it returned a "no"-answer because in the beginning we already required that  halts in either  or  ? And that's because we supposed that it is decidable, so it always has to halt?

Comment: @rici And the fact that it halts in those states is necessary because if we had a loop the problem would’t be decidable since being decidable means that you halt for every input. Am I correct?

Comment: yes, in order to decide, the machine must halt. Until it halts, the decision hasn't been made.

Comment: @rici Thank you. One last question: In the last machine (H^) we modify the output of the actual halting problem solver (H).  Why are we allowed to do that? We prove that H doesn’t exist, but meanwhile we are modifying the “inside” of the H-machine. Isn’t that a problem?

Comment: this is a proof by contradiction. If $H$ existed, we could construct $\widehat{H}$. But $\widehat{H}$ cannot  exist. Conclusion: $H$ cannot exist.

Comment: @rici I think I get that, but we are getting inside 'H' and changing its states. Are we allowed to do such a thing? I would expect that we just used H as a black box (and then came to a contradiction in that way).

Comment: This is mathematics, not programming. We're not actually modifying anything; we're describing how to construct $\widehat{H}$. And the point I made earlier stands: If $H$ existed, we could produce $\widehat{H}$ using a simple algorithm. We don't have to run the algorithm; that implication is simply true. But $\widehat{H}$ cannot exist. So it must be the case that $H$ doesn't exist.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_proof#Proof_by_contradiction

Comment: @rici I get it now,, thanks.